# php array display two titles at a time

Tags: php

I've got an array of 28 titles and i need to run through the array and display 2 items(titles) at a time into the following html:

```
<ul>
    //start loop here for all items in array
    <li>
        //display two titles in seperate divs
        <div class="item1">
            <h1>title[x]</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <h1>title[x]</h1>
        </div>
    </li>
    //repeat...
</ul>
```

So basically it outputs like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 2</h1>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 4</h1>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 5</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Title 6</h1>
        </div>
    </li>
    //etc..
</ul>
```

This is what I've tried so far, obviously it just duplicated both titles.

```
<div id="work-list">

    <ul class="work-list-cat group">

    <?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) { 

    foreach($this->intro_items as $id => $item) {
        $itemarray[] = $item;
    }

    $count = count($itemarray);

    $item = 1;

    for($y = 0; $y < $count; $y++) {
    ?>

    <li style="width:33.333333333333333333333333333333%; height:100%; float:left;">

        <?php 
                for($x=0; $x<$item; $x++){ ?>
                <div style="width:100%; height:50%; float:left; background-color:#333;">
                <?php echo $itemarray[$y]->title; ?>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%; height:50%; float:left; background-color:#444;">
                <?php echo $itemarray[$y]->title; ?>
                </div>
            <?php   } ?>
    </li>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

    </ul>

</div>  <?php //End of #work-list ?>
```

Comment: This isn't really a question. We like to see a clear question with code examples of what you've tried already, what is expected (you show that), and what happens instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, and you're stumped because it's not working with a `foreach` loop, I reckon? It's times like these that the good ol' for-loop comes in handy, incrementing the index with 2 at a time. Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
<ul>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 2) { ?>
    <li>
        //display two titles in seperate divs
        <div class="item1">
            <h1><? echo $array[$i]; ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <h1><? if ($i + 1 < count($array)) echo $array[$i + 1]; ?></h1>
        </div>
    </li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

Note: it won't work for arrays with an odd number of elements, but seeing as you have 28, that shouldn't be an issue. EDIT: When there's an odd number of elements, it will simply print an empty div and h1-tag at the end.

PS: As you didn't ask a really specific question, I could've misinterpreted your problem entirely.. Try to be a bit more precise in formulating the issue if this doesn't help you out.

Comment: If I had 29 items would it just print a blank entry then?

Comment: It would access an out of bounds array element. When $i is 28, it would still pass $i < count($array) and try both index [28] and [29]. I've updated the code slightly so that it will leave out the non-existent 30th element.

Answer (score 1):

I usualy don't give such a chewed code, but here we go:

```
<ul>
<?php for($i=0;$i<28;$i+=2){
    echo '
    <li>
        <div class="item1">
            <h1>'.$title[$i].'</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <h1>'.$title[$i+1].'</h1>
        </div>
    </li>';
  } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're thinking about PHP here? Concatenation required a dot, the variables should be preceded with $'s and the int keyword doesn't quite go there.

Comment: totally right...I was just coding in java and mixed everything :P

Comment: Cheers that was what I was looking for. i+=2 then outputting using i+1. Didn't know that. :/